# jQuery - .animate() issue, "stepping"

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am having an issue with the jQuery .animate() function.   If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/8fvJN/12/ - you will see that when you hover over a box, several things all happen at the same time: the box gets bigger, the title font increases slightly in size and the image gets larger.   This all happens simultaniously.

However, when you hover out of the box, instead of the reverting back to the original size all at once, it does it in two steps.   I cannot figure out why its "stepping" like that and I need it to simultanious like it is when you hover.

Whats my problem?

Thanks
Zach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This seems to do the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/8fvJN/13/).